# C code, compiler Xcode, detected source and destination buffer overlap

Tags: c, xcode

I'm doing a project for school in which I have to create a program that plays go fish. In which a deck of cards is in a doubly linked list. I read the cards from a file in the function Addcard. I have a function to print the cards and a function that is supposed to shuffle the cards. I have ot use the parameters of the struct to implement the cards. I sometimes see the error "detected source and destination buffer overlap" when I run the shuffle function, sometimes not. When the error comes up it says Thread 1: signal SIGABRT next to a string copy function. I believe it has something to do with the buffer size of some kind of allocated memory being too small, but I don't really know how to fix it. Any help would be more then appreciated. Here is an excerpt of the code I have written.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct card_s{
char suit[7];
int value;
struct card_s *next, *previous;
}card;

int rand_gen(int count){
    double frac;
    frac = (double)rand()/((double)RAND_MAX+1);
    return floor(count * frac); //random number in [0, count]
}



void addCard(card *p, card **hl, card **hr, FILE *inp){

card *temp; // pointer to a node_t
temp = (card *)malloc(sizeof (card)); // new node creation

       fscanf(inp, "%d", &temp->value);
fscanf(inp, "%s", temp->suit);


                    if (*hl == NULL){ // if left head is null, i.e., list is empty
                        temp->previous = NULL;
                        temp->next = NULL;
                        *hl = temp;
                        *hr = temp;
                    }
                    else if (p->next == NULL){ // if adding at the end of list
                          temp->previous = p;
                        temp->next = NULL;
                        p->next = temp;
                        *hr = temp;
                    }
                    else{     // if adding to the middle of the list
                        temp->next = p-> next;
                        temp->previous = p;
                        p->next = temp;
                        temp->next->previous = temp;
                    }
                    }

void Print(card **headl)  { //this function prints from left to right only
    card *temp;
    temp = (*headl);
    while(temp != NULL) {
        printf("|");
        printf("%d", temp->value);
        if(strcmp(temp->suit,"hea")==0) {
            printf("♥");
        }
        if(strcmp(temp->suit,"clu")==0) {
            printf("♣");
        }
        if(strcmp(temp->suit,"spa")==0) {
            printf("♠");
        }
        if(strcmp(temp->suit,"dia")==0) {
            printf("♦");
        }
        printf("|");
        //printf("%s ", temp->suit);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
void Print1(card **headl)  { //this function prints from left to right only
card *temp;
temp = (*headl);
while(temp != NULL) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
    printf("|");
        if(temp->value == 11){
           printf("J");
        }
        else if(temp->value == 12) {
            printf("Q");
        }
        else if(temp->value == 13) {
            printf("K");
        }
        else if(temp->value == 14) {
            printf("A");
        }
        else {
            printf("%d", temp->value);
        }

    if(strcmp(temp->suit,"h")==0) {
        printf("♥");
    }
    if(strcmp(temp->suit,"c")==0) {
        printf("♣");
    }
    if(strcmp(temp->suit,"s")==0) {
        printf("♠");
    }
    if(strcmp(temp->suit,"d")==0) {
        printf("♦");
    }
    printf("|");

    //printf("%s ", temp->suit);
    temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
}

void swap(card *pt, int i, int j) {

card *temp;
temp = (card *)malloc(sizeof(card));
card *temp1 = pt, *temp2 = pt;  //creates temperaries that start from the head left

for(int x = 0; x < i; x++) { //counts the number of nodes until i
    temp1 = temp1->next;
}

for(int x = 0; x < j; x++) { //counts the number of nodes until j
    temp2 = temp2->next;
}
temp->value = temp1->value;  //swaps the information not the nodes
strcpy(temp->suit,temp1->suit);
temp1->value = temp2->value;
strcpy(temp1->suit, temp2->suit);
temp2->value = temp->value;
strcpy(temp2->suit, temp->suit);

}




int main(void)  {
FILE *inp = NULL;
inp = fopen("cards.txt", "r");
srand((int)time(NULL));
card *headl = NULL, *headr = NULL;

for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
    addCard(headr, &headl, &headr, inp);
}

if(inp == NULL) {
    printf("No file found");
    return -1;
}

printIntro();

printf("\n");

Print1(&headl);

printf("\n");
printf("\n");


for(int i = 0; i <= 45; i++) {  //does the swap function swap number times
        swap(headl, rand_gen(52), rand_gen(52));
       }

Print1(&headl);


return(0);
}
```

Comment: You don't check whether the member `next` is `NULL` (which I suppose the last element of a linked list could be) before dereferencing it. Also you have made it hard to read the poorly formatted code, but I notice in function `swap` you have a memory leak. Why do you need dynamic memory for `temp` when you could use a local `struct`?

Comment: This is the first time I have taken a coding class and the first time posting on stack overflow, I'm sorry if the code is poorly formatted. I honetly don't know how I would implement a local struct. For my future refence how would I more properlly format my code? Also the spacing is weird in my code becuase I copied and pasted it onto here, maybe that is why.

Comment: In function `swap` you could define the local variable `card temp;` and then `temp.value = temp1->value;` etc. But in function `addCard` you still need to allocate memory for the new node because a local variable goes out of scope when the function returns and does not persist.

Comment: . . . as for code formatting, the compiler doesn't care, but code is more readable (by its author too) if consistent whitespace and indentation are used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error message saying "detected source and destination buffer overlap", near a string copy function, which copies data from a source to a destination...

Are there any instances of `strcpy` where the source and dest might point to the same memory?

I see these two lines:

```
card *temp1 = pt, *temp2 = pt;  //creates temperaries that start from the head left
//advance `temp1` `i` times, and `temp2` `j` times
... 
strcpy(temp1->suit, temp2->suit);
```

What happens when `i` and `j` are the same value?

Comment: You might want to use an `#include <assert.h> . . . assert(i != j);` if you believe this cannot happen; debug mode in `xCode` is pretty painless, I find.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that, if they were both pointing to the same destination would it cuase that problem? Could I convert I and J into temp variables in the swap function and then have an if statement that did something like if(i == j) { j = j+1;}

Comment: I made it so I and J can't be the same, and it fixed it. Thank you so much. Is there any way that you could explain why it breaks if they are the same? I'm having a little bit of a hard time in figuring it out.

Comment: The exact answer is because the standard says they shouldn't be the same: `The strcpy() function shall copy the string pointed to by s2 (including the terminating null byte) into the array pointed to by s1. If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined.` .   The practical reason is because libraries are free to implement strcpy any way they want. There's no guarantee that it won't modify part of the destination before it is read.